# Get meta tags from external URL using Ruby on Rails and Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm creating a form which contains the fields "URL", "Title" and "Image". I'd like to update the value of title and image textboxes when user paste a URL in the first field(onkeyup). These values could come from meta tags. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform an [ajax request](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch) to a second endpoint within your app, which sends the url that the user has entered. That endpoint would use the [opengraph gem](https://github.com/intridea/opengraph#usage) which extracts the metadata and returns it to the page as json data. That data would then be used to populate the other form fields.